# jQuery attribute issue - trying to retrieve div id and class information

Tags: jquery, attributes

This is probably simple but am very new to jQuery.

I'm trying to retrieve a div id and the last part of a div class to make them display:none.

Here is an example of what I current have:

```
<div id="content-right">
<div class="item107 item-image">..content here..</div>
</div>

<script>
$("document").ready(function()
{
$("[id="#content-right"][class$=item-image]").css({"display": "none"});  

}); </script>
```

---

("[id="#content-right"][class$=item-image]")  ...this is the section of code I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("#content-right .item-image").css({"display": "none"});
```

Or:

```
$("#content-right .item-image").hide();
```

This hides the div with the `item-image` class.

If you want to hide both, you can just hide its parent:

```
$('#content-right').hide();
```

If you want to select both, you can do:

```
$("#content-right, .item-image");
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the div in your example, use:

```
$("#content-right .item-image").hide();
```

This will select any element that has the class `item-image` that is a descendant of the element with the id of `content-right`, and changes the display property to none.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is overly complex for what you're trying to achieve, also you appear to be using quotes incorrectly, you can reduce your code to:

```
$("#content-right .item-image").hide();
```

The [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function has the same effect as `css({'display':'none'})`.

Check out [this article](http://sunali.com/2010/02/03/introduction-to-jquery-and-jquery-selectors/) to **learn all about the different types of selectors**.